# any local minimum of a convex function is a global minimum over a convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, proof-explanation, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

in this proof I can't see the contradiction that the author of this proof is talking about when $\lambda \to 1$

is it just the fact that $f(\overline{x}) < f(\overline{x}) $ is non-sense or something else ?

[image: Proof of the theorem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a  $ 0 < \lambda < 1 $ close enough to $1$, one has 
$$  \lambda \bar{x} + (1-\lambda)z \in B(\bar{x}, \epsilon)$$

while we have  $f \left( \lambda \bar{x} + (1-\lambda)z\right) < f(\bar{x})
$

which is contradicting with $\bar{x}$ being local minimum.

Comment: I have a small question related to your answer when  -> 1 why we have ¯+(1−)∈(¯,)?

Comment: because    $ \bar{x} \in B(\bar{x}, \epsilon)$  @Ben10

Answer (score 1):

As $\lambda \to 1$ you have, as he says,
$$
\lim_{\lambda \to 1} f \left( \lambda \bar{x} + (1-\lambda)z\right)
= f\left(\bar{x}\right)
$$
so the inequality becomes
$$
f\left(\bar{x}\right) < f\left(\bar{x}\right),
$$
an obvious contradiction.

Comment: that's what I thought he meant. but I feel like there's something wrong somewhere but it's probably just to me. thanks for the clarification btw

Comment: That' not a correct way of thinking of proof!  @rapidracim

Comment: when you take limit, at most you have $\leq$ not $<$

Comment: @Redshoes i disagree, the limit is inside $f$; if it was outside, would be a different story